# check if field exists in match query aggregation mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, match

i have a mongodb collection of events from which i want to get the current availablae events so i am using match query like that

```
   Event.aggregate([ { $match: { isActive: true, ...matchQuery, startDate:{$lt:today}, endDate:{$gt:today} } },])
```

the problem is that not all the events in my database have startDate and enDate fields and i want to get those events too , so i want to check if startDate and endDate exists then they should be lt and gt than today if they don't exist and the document match the rest of the query , i want to get it . i tried this way but doesn't work

```
{ $match: { isEnabled: true, ...matchQuery, startDate ? {startDate:{$lt:today}}, endDate ?  endDate:{$gt:today} } },
```

thank you

Comment: Please add your sample data and query here https://mongoplayground.net/ and update the link in the strory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the idea is to fetch all documents where:

1. `startDate` **AND** `endDate` does not exits.

**OR**

2. `today` is between the range `startDate` **AND** `endDate`.

Try this:

```js
let today = new Date();

db.events.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            isActive: true,
            $or: [
                {
                    startDate: { $exists: false },
                    endDate: { $exists: false }
                },
                {
                    startDate: { $lt: today },
                    endDate: { $gt: today }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "isActive" : true,
    "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2021-03-31T00:00:00.000+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "isActive" : true
}
```

Test data:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "isActive" : true,
    "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2021-03-31T00:00:00.000+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "isActive" : true,
    "endDate" : ISODate("2021-03-31T00:00:00.000+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "isActive" : true,
    "startDate" : ISODate("2021-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "isActive" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "isActive" : true,
    "startDate" : ISODate("2021-02-01T00:00:00.000+05:30"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2021-03-03T00:00:00.000+05:30")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , your answer is logic and it helped me . Thank you

Comment: Why your aggregate query not using `$expr` in `$match`  stage ?

Comment: `$expr` is used to compare fields from the same document in a `$match` stage. In the above query the comparison is between the fields in a document (`startDate`, `endDate`) and external variable (`today` or a constant value `false`).

Comment: Check: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#behavior